# Grails mongodb plugin, handling relation cycles

Tags: mongodb, grails, associations, grails-orm

Given a profile in a social network:

```
Class Profile {
   String name
   List<Profile> friends

   static hasMany = [friends:Profile]
}
```

Imagine a profile A which is friend with profile B and vice versa:

```
a.addToFriends(b)
b.addToFriends(a)
```

When loading a profile like

```
def p = Profile.get(id)
```

the cycle results in a stack overflow as all associations are being loaded down to any depth. Looks like the [mongodb plugin](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) does not support lazy loading which would prevent the vicious loading cycle. My soultion is to use the low level gmongo API, store ObjectIDs in the friends collection and load the associations manually in a ProfileService.getProfileById() method. This is working fine but I'd prefer to use GORM as much as possible. Now I can't use GORM at all for such classes with possible cycles. Is there a way to teach the mongodb plugin lazy loading? I already tried to set fetchMode to lazy but it just didn't work.... Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 MongoDB Gorm plugins for Grails as I know. If you are using [the one based on morphia](https://github.com/jkuehn/gorm-mongodb), lazy referencing could be defined via `@Reference(lazy=true)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the other plugin. Yes, I decided for [SpringSource's mongodb](http://grails.org/plugin/mongodb) plugin. I thought it might be well integrated as it is part of the grails-data-mapping project. But if my problem is solved by the morphia based plugin I might switch. I'll evaluate it.